# error : unable to connect to database ? using mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

here is my app.module.ts file

````
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
  })],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}```
````

Comment: Evidently `process.env.MONGO_URI` is undefined, we can't give you much insight as to why except: you didn't set the env var.

Comment: my .env file is-
MONGO_URI='mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up configuration. Read this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).